# Limit for big system size of Fokker-Planck eigenfunctions

Tags: quantum-mechanics, statistical-mechanics, operators, mathematical-physics, stochastic-processes

I am learning how to use diagonalization methods applied to Fokker-Planck equations with [Gardiner's book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/3540707123) and [these notes](https://personal.math.ubc.ca/%7Eholmescerfon/teaching/asa22/handout-Lecture12_2022.pdf). The idea is to find the probability density, $ P[X_t\in[x,x+dx]]=\rho_t \, dx$, as an expansion on the basis of eigenfunctions of the Fokker-Planck operator,
$$ \rho_t=\sum_\lambda C_\lambda(t) R_\lambda,$$
with
$$ \mathcal{L}R_\lambda=-\lambda R_\lambda,$$
and
$$\partial_t \rho_t(x)= \mathcal{L}\rho_t.$$

The references I provided work out the simple example of an unbiased Brownian motion trapped in a segment of length $L$ by two reflecting boundary conditions. This corresponds to the equations
\begin{equation}
\begin{cases}
\partial_t \rho_t(x)= D\partial_x^2 \rho_t,\\
\partial_x \rho_t|_{x=0}=\partial_x \rho_t|_{x=L}0.
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
The solution to this problem when $\rho_{t=0}=\delta(x-x_0)$ reads
$$ \rho_t= \frac{1}{L}+\frac{2}{L}\sum_{n=1}^\infty \cos\left(\frac{n\pi x_0}{L}\right)\cos\left(\frac{n\pi x}{L}\right)e^{-D\left(\frac{n\pi}{L}\right)^2 t}.$$

Where the sum describes the transitory modes towards the stationary solution, $ \lim_{t\to\infty}\rho_t=1/L$.

For this example, the limit $L\to\infty$ does not make much sense since the process would be delocalized at large times and therefore there is no stationary distribution. I repeated the calculations for a process that is biased towards $x=0$, so that the process remains localized for both $L,t\to \infty$. The bias is just a constant negative drift, $v<0$. The equations now read
\begin{equation}
\begin{cases}
\partial_t \rho_t(x)= -v\partial_x \rho_t+D\partial_x^2 \rho_t,\\
v\rho_t-D\partial_x \rho_t|_{x=0}=v\rho_t-D\partial_x \rho_t|_{x=L}0.
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
I couldn't find the solution to this problem in the literature, the one that I find is
$$ \rho_t= \frac{\gamma\, e^{-\gamma x}}{1-\exp(-\gamma L)}+\frac{2}{L}e^{-\gamma(x-x_0)/2-D\frac{\gamma^2}{4} t}\sum_{n=1}^\infty S_n.$$
with
$$ S_n =\left[ \frac{\gamma}{2}\sin\left(\frac{n\pi x_0}{L}\right)+\frac{n\pi }{L}\cos\left(\frac{n\pi x_0}{L}
\right)\right]\left[ \frac{\gamma}{2}\sin\left(\frac{n\pi x}{L}\right)+\frac{n\pi }{L}\cos\left(\frac{n\pi x}{L}
\right)\right]\frac{e^{-D\left(\frac{n\pi}{L}\right)^2  t}}{\frac{\gamma^2}{4}+\left(\frac{n\pi x}{L}\right)^2}$$
With $\gamma=-v/D$. One more time, the sum characterizes the transient towards the known stationary distribution, $\lim_{L\to\infty} \rho_t=\frac{\gamma\, e^{-\gamma x}}{1-\exp(-\gamma L)}$. Also, I recover the unbiased solution when computing the limit $\lim_{\gamma\to 0}\rho_t$. I could check the correctness of the expression computing numerically the sum and comparing with the analytical result that I found in [this paper, Eq. (3.2)](https://doi.org/10.1137/060663258)

Indeed, in this case the stationary distribution is well-defined in the limit $\lim_{L\to\infty}$. Nevertheless, I'm having trouble to compute the limit $L\to\infty$ for the transient since the separate contribution for all transient modes equal zero,

$$\lim_{L\to \infty}\frac{1}{L} S_n=0.$$

Any ideas on how to compute this limit correctly? I guess I should do the limit of the sum instead of the sum of limits, but I don't now how. Also, this seems the kind of pedagogic problem that should be solved somewhere, are you aware of a reference using this approach to tackle this problem?

Answer (score 1):

To get an interesting continuum limit, you need to evaluate the entire $\rho_t$. Indeed, while each individual team is zero, the sum is infinite and you are looking at the region where it is barely convergent, i.e. $t\to0$, so you do get a meaningful result. Btw, another way to get the limit $L\to\infty$ at finite time is to instead look a finite $L$ and send $t\to0$. Intuitively, the initial transience does not have time to "feel" the size of the domain which is why it is equivalent to solving for the unlimited domain.

In the unbiased case, you recognise a Riemann sum for the integral:
$$
\begin{align}
\rho_t &\xrightarrow{L\to\infty} \int_0^{+\infty}2\cos(kx_0)\cos(kx)e^{-Dk^2t}\frac{dk}{\pi} \\
&= \frac{e^{-(x-x_0)^2/4Dt}}{\sqrt{4\pi Dt}}+\frac{e^{-(x+x_0)^2/4Dt}}{\sqrt{4\pi Dt}}
\end{align}
$$
You can then perform the integral being gaussian. This agrees with directly solving the diffusion equation on the entire half line (the limiting domain of $(0,L)$ when $L\to\infty$) with initial condition $\rho_0(x)=\delta(x-x_0)$. It is easier to see if you rather use the method of images:
$$
\rho_t = \sum_{n\in\mathbb Z} \frac{e^{-(x-x_0-n2L)^2/4Dt}}{\sqrt{4\pi Dt}}+\frac{e^{-(x+x_0-n2L)^2/4Dt}}{\sqrt{4\pi Dt}}
$$
and as $L\to\infty$ the contributions of the images $n\neq0$ go to zero. In fact, you can also kill the image due to the boundary at $x=0$ if you change your domain to $(-L/2,L/2)$. You'll only get the bulk contribution, as the limiting domain is the entire real line. Mathematically, the easiest way to see this is rather to use periodic boundary conditions to recover the real line diffusion.

The same method applies for advection. You again recognise the Riemann sum which becomes an integral:
$$
\begin{align}
\rho_t &\xrightarrow{L\to\infty} \gamma e^{-\gamma x}+\int_0^{+\infty}2e^{-\gamma(x-x_0)/2}\cos(kx_0)\cos(kx)e^{-D(k^2+\gamma^2/4)t}\frac{dk}{\pi} \\
&= \gamma e^{-\gamma x}+e^{-\gamma(x-x_0)/2-D\gamma^2t/4}\left(\frac{e^{-(x-x_0)^2/4Dt}}{\sqrt{4\pi Dt}}+\frac{e^{-(x+x_0)^2/4Dt}}{\sqrt{4\pi Dt}}\right)
\end{align}
$$
You can also use the method of images This time it's a bit trickier but you need to reflect the current $j=\rho-\partial_x\rho$ so that it is antisymmetric. This leads to slightly more involved image for $\rho$. Furthermore, for the time evolution, you need to be careful as the image solution is advected with the opposite velocity.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I had an error in my first version of the question, I edited it  with the correct expression for the eigenvalues. In any case, your hint was very useful! Do you know of a reference where the problem is solved with the method of images? I only saw the method of images applied to absorbing boundaries and I cannot properly reflect the current.